# Make array depth from basic array

Tags: php, arrays

I confused how to make depth from basic array.

```
$array = array('736', '827', '831');
```

With foreach loop, I want final result like this:

```
Array
(
    [736] => Array
        (
            [827] => Array
                (
                    [831] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Hint: recursion

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The way you do this is by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: Thanks for comment, but as i talk, i confused. so absolutely, i can't give minimal sample.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code you have written, tell us what problems you have with that code. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me service". If you want someone to write your code for you, you can hire a programmer. If you want an answer on [so], you need to demonstrate some willingness to solve the problem yourself. Please, read [ask] and how to construct a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you want them, do this:

```
array
(
    736 => array
        (
            827 => array
                (
                    831 => array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

or did I misunderstand the question?

using a foreach backwards:

```
$arr=array(831,827,736);
$newref=array();
foreach($arr as $el)
{
    $newref=array($el=>$newref);
}
```

for reversing an array: $arr=array_reverse($arr);

Comment: I want convert basic array to that with foreach.

Comment: @Opsional Are you sure you want a foreach? You can do this: $arr[736][827][831]=array(); to get the above result...

Comment: But the value is auto-generated, so the value i listed here only sample.

Comment: Give an error, `syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) `

Comment: sorry, forgot the array ()

Comment: Thanks, for perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the most efficient, but something like this should do it.

```
function nestedArray($array) {
  $newArray = [];
  $pointer = &$newArray;
  foreach($array as $value) {
    $pointer[$value] = [];
    $pointer = &$pointer[$value];
  }

  return $newArray;
}

$arr = [736, 827, 831];

var_dump(nestedArray($arr));
```